# This is simple C++ program to find number of paths in a DAG but I am getting SIGSEGV error?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, directed-acyclic-graphs

According to me I am not trying to access an array element out of bounds or trying to use too much memory.
Link to the problem that I am trying to do [https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/count-the-paths4332/1/?category[]=Graph&category[]=Graph&difficulty[]=-2&difficulty[]=-1&difficulty[]=0&page=1&query=category[]Graphdifficulty[]-2difficulty[]-1difficulty[]0page1category[]Graph#](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/count-the-paths4332/1/?category%5B%5D=Graph&category%5B%5D=Graph&difficulty%5B%5D=-2&difficulty%5B%5D=-1&difficulty%5B%5D=0&page=1&query=category%5B%5DGraphdifficulty%5B%5D-2difficulty%5B%5D-1difficulty%5B%5D0page1category%5B%5DGraph#)

please help me with this and also provide any suggestions to prevent SIGSEV error

```cpp
class Solution{
public:
    void path_count(vector<vector<int>>edges, int n, int start, int destination,
                    vector<bool> &visited, int &count){
        if(start == destination){
            count++;
            return;
        }
        visited[start] = true;
        
        for(auto next : edges[start]){
            if(visited[next] == false){
                path_count(edges, n, next, destination, visited, count);
            }
        }
    
       visited[start] = false;
    }
    
    int possible_paths(vector<vector<int>>edges, int n, int start, int destination){
        
        vector<bool> visited(n, false);
        int count = 0;
        path_count(edges, n, start, destination, visited, count);
        return count;
    }
};


Update : This problem is solved following this 
[Answer][1]
But you could suggest me on how to avoid SIGSEV error and const
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not just your submission to some online challenge. That also includes input, unless you can hard-code it inline! As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I have added the problems link where it has example explained

Comment: Don't pass `edges` by value, pass it by reference to avoid it being copied each time.  `void path_count(vector<vector<int>>& edges,...)` Same thing for `possible_paths` function.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `edges` by `const&`, not by value, e.g. `void path_count(const vector<vector<int>> &edges, int n, int start, int destination,vector<bool> &visited, int &count)` and `int possible_paths(const vector<vector<int>> &edges, int n, int start, int destination)`

Otherwise you are performing a full copy of the graph for every single recursion level, which will cause you to go out-of-memory for every non-trivial input.

Also, you did interpret `edges` incorrectly. `edges` is not in the form `edge[source][destination]`, but in the form `edges[{source, destination}, {source, destination}, ...]`:

```
    for(const auto& edge : edges){
        const auto& next = edge[1];
        if(edge[0] == start && visited[next] == false){
            path_count(edges, n, next, destination, visited, count);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solved my problem I actually misinterpreted the input.